# Record video from VideoView

Tags: android, live-streaming, video-recording

Currently doing project on live Streaming, and I succeed to play live video. Now my next task is to record the video which is playing in VideoView. 
I had searched, able to found capturing video but with surface(camera) but here in VideoView I am not having any surface.

any help appreciated

Comment: Did you get solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27565298/4811470) link. In short your server has to support downloading. If it does, you can try the following code:

```
private final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 5000; //5sec
private final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 30000; //30sec
private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 5; // 5MB

private final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 5000; //5sec
private final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 30000; //30sec
private final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 5; // 5MB

try {
  URL url = new URL("http://....");

  //Open a connection to that URL.
  URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
  ucon.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
  ucon.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

  // Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
  // uses 5KB download buffer
  InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
  BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
  byte[] buff = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];

  int len = 0;
  while ((len = in.read(buff)) != -1)
  {
      out.write(buff,0,len);
  }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  // Handle the error
} finally {
  if(in != null) {
    try {
      in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Nothing you can do
    }
  }
  if(out != null) {
    try {
      out.flush();
      out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Nothing you can do
    }
  }
}
```

If the server doesn't support downloading, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use platform-tools and record video using:

```
adb shell screenrecord --verbose /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

Replace Demo with whatever file name you want.
Also this will be placed on your phone, and defaults to 6 minutes I believe.
Check out the options of screen record.

To pull the file to your computer.... (the following command, or use Android Device Monitor

```
adb pull /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

I have used this to record demo's of apps, and even played youtube, and had it record that.
It does not have audio, so that may be a major problem.
But this is included in the sdk, and records any screen showing while it is recording.

Comment: Note: this will just record when you wish to record, and not programmatically.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Also it will record whole application's screen rather I want to record video which is playing in VideoView.