# How to record video from Videoview in android?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, rtsp, android-videoview

Play RTPS video from URL. its working fine but try to record this Video 
Its possible to record video from Videoview.

```
 String vidAddress = "rtsp://192.168.42.1/live";
    Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidAddress);
VideoView vidView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideo);
 vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);
        vidView.start();
```

Comment: `but try to record this Video` show how you tried

Comment: Also why do you want to record video from the view, not from the original URL?

Comment: its Possible to download from url ??

Comment: yes you can download if you know the file format

Comment: its RTSP Live streaming #

Comment: sure, just google for `android record rtsp stream`

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9091014/record-video-from-videoview